# Calling To Method Async Without Waiting For Answer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I've MVC application and I want to keep Activity Log about the activity in my site, so for example, 
if user is log-in successfully ill insert to my database a row that describe this activity (user with the name X log-in in time Y with ip of Z.

The problem is that I need to wait for the result, I don't care for the result, I don't want the result to hold me back, I want to send it to the function (the update Activity table in the DB function) and to continue.

**I'll start for the bottom up :**

This is my Data Query function :

```
public static void InsertLogRecord(LogRecord lg)
{
    try
    {
         string query = "INSERT INTO ActivityLog VALUES('" + lg.Id + "','" + lg.Time + "','" + lg.Executor + "','" + lg.ExecutedOn + "','" + lg.Action + "','" + lg.StartState + "','" + lg.EndState + "','" + lg.IP + "')";

         AdoHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(query);
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         throw ex;
    }

}
```

This is my Controller function (that called the previous "InsertLogRecord" function)

```
public void UpdateLog(string exeOn, string action, string sState, string eState)
{
     LogRecord lg = new LogRecord(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), DateTime.Now, User.Identity.Name, exeOn, action, sState, eState, Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]);

     DataQueries.InsertLogRecord(lg);
}
```

Use Example: (store an action record on the log, "user log-in")

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:

              // Just before redirecting the user to the site I want to store the info' on my DB

             UpdateLog("", "Log in", "", "");

            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);


        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
    }
}
```

How can I do it properly ?

Comment: [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) by Scott Hanselman describes all the popular options. QueueBackgroundWorkItem, Hangfire, Quartz.NET, Webbackgrounder, FluentScheduler etc.

Comment: Simply don't await the task. To make it more explicit, use `Task.Run(() => Log())`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need is a reliable way to queue the item in a "Fire and Forget" fasion. What you could do is use [`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) introduced in .NET 4.5.2 which queues work and notifies the ASP.NET environment, such that when it attempts to recycle your app, it will know pending work is still at play.

If you're using previous version of the .NET framework, you could use Stephan Clearys [`BackgroundTaskManager`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks).

I also recommend reading stephans post on [Fire and Forget in ASP.NET](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)

**Edit:**

In order to queue work using `HostingEnvironment`, simply pass it a delegate. It can be either an `Action<CancellationToken>` or a `Func<CancellationToken, Task>`.

Here's an example using a Lambda Expression:

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(cancellationToken =>
{
   // Put code here.
});
```

Comment: Thank you Yuval, i'm trying to get this thing, if you have more good examples or articles about QeueueBackgroundWorkItem its will help me.
Thanks again.

Comment: Check [this](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/05/07/scheduling-background-jobs-from-an-asp-net-application-in-net-4-5-2) out. Also, edited my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Yuval I used the RegiesterObject(the previous version of the QueueBackgroundWorkItem) because I'm not using the 4.5.2, works perfectly, thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Yuval if you could check this question regarding the exception handling in this environment:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647520/get-the-exception-from-background-worker-hostingenvironment-registerobject

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using the async version of ExecuteNonQuery?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223678(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

```
AdoHelper.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(query);
```

Comment: For some reason it doesnt update my table.
I change my ado helper function to this :

 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);

                command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
.
I just added the Async to the method name.
Not working, and i dont know why, and not throwing exception.

Comment: I'm guessing since it's wrapped in a USING statement, the SqlConnection is getting disposed too soon.  Can you try just getting rid of the using statement and just newing up a SqlConnection?  (Just to verify that this is the issue)

Comment: If you're using an async method without `await`, there is no guarantee regarding the execution of the `Task`. It could potentially throw an exception which will go on ignored and you won't know why your database isn't updating. I wouldn't recommend doing that.

Comment: True.  In this case they're just log entries though.  What are you going to do if your logger throws an exception?  Log it?  :-)

Comment: @Brad If he's especially inserting it to the DB, it must matter to someone, else he wouldn't be doing it, would he?

Comment: You'd have to ask him about that.  You make a very good point about database crud operations in general though. Normally you would definitely want to know if one failed.